# memcpy for multidimensional array

Tags: c

Is there a way we can copy every element from one multidimensional array to another multidimensional array by just doing one memcpy operation?

```
int array1[4][4][4][4];
int array2[4][4][4][4];
int main()
{
    memset(&array1,1,sizeof(array1));
    memset(&array2,0,sizeof(array2));
    printf_all("value in array2 %d \n",array2[1][1][1][1]);
    memcpy(&array2,&array1,sizeof(array2));
    printf("memcopied in array2 from array1 \n");
    printf("value in array2 %d \n",array2[1][1][1][1]); //not printing 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct.  You should *not* expect the output to show you a value of `1`.  You should expect it to show you a value of `16843009`, assuming a 4 byte `int`.

The reason is: you are filling `array1` with *bytes* of value `1`, not with *ints* of value `1`.  i.e. binary `00000001000000010000000100000001` (`0x01010101`) is being filled into all the `int` elements with your `memset` operation.

So regardless of the size of `int` on your machine (unless it's a single byte!) you should not expect to see the value `1`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code should already be correct.

You have to consider memory layout when doing this. The arrays are all in one block, multi dimensional is essentially a math trick done by the compiler.

Your code says copy this memory content to the other memory block. since both share the same layout they will contain the same values.

The following code also just copies the values, but access is handled differently so you would have to think about how to get the order of elements correct.

```
int array1[4][4][4][4]; //elements 256
int array2[256]; 

int main()
{
    memcpy(&array2,&array1,sizeof(array1)); //will also copy
    // original access via: a + 4 * b + 16 * c + 64 * d
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to consider anything? `array1` and `array2` have the same type, so it should be possible to assign values by copying the underlying representation.

Comment: Suppose you wanted to copy something different. 
Like an array of char * or a big char buffer where the elements are seperated by \0.
Saying it like this it seems obvious but that is from a real world example.

Answer (score 1):

Multidimensional array in C is a flat block of memory with no internal structure. Memory layout of a multidimensional array is exactly the same as that of a 1-dimensional array of the same total size. The multidimensional interface is implemented through simple index recalculation. You can always `memcpy` the whole multidimensional array exactly as you do it in your code.

This, of course, only applies to built-in multidimensional arrays, explicitly declared as such (as in your code sample). If you implement a hand-made multidimensional array as an array of pointers to sub-arrays, that data structure will not be copyable in one shot with `memcpy`.

However, apparently you have some misconceptions about how `memset` works. Your `memset(&array1,1,sizeof(array1));` will not fill the array with `1`s, meaning that your code is not supposed to print `1` regardless of which array you print. `memset` interprets target memory as an array of `char`s, not as an array of `int`s.

`memset` can be used to set memory to zero. As for non-zero values, `memset` is generally unsuitable for initializing arrays of any type other than `char`.