# How to copy a char** using memcpy

Tags: c

I have two char ** variables :

```
char ** a;
char ** b;
```

with `a` containing a bunch of char arrays and so does `b`, after reallocing the memory of `a`, I wanted to append it with b char arrays, as it showen below:

```
memcpy(a + oldSizeOfA, b, sizeOfB);
```

I'm expecting that all of the char arrays in `b` will be in `a`, what am I doing wrong ?

I tried to simplify my code to this :

```
char ** a = (char **)malloc(5*sizeof(char*));
char ** b = (char **)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    b[i] = (char *)malloc(4);
    strcpy(b,"tes");

    a[i] = (char *)malloc(4);
    strcpy(a,"tes");
}

memcpy(&a + 5, &b, 5);
```

Comment: memcpy will only work to copy one *CONTIGUOUS* block to another.  That may or may not be applicable here.  It depends on how the character arrays - as well as the array of character arrays - was allocated in the first place.  Q: I assume you know the #/character arrays in a and b?  And the length of each character array in *a and *b?

Comment: You didn't provide enough information. You need to show more code, possibly a [MCVE].

Comment: I am not sure but I think that `a` and `b` need to be 2D arrays and not just pointers to pointers. If you have two 2D arrays than check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188085/memcpy-for-multidimensional-array

Comment: ok, my bad, I just updated my post with an example.

Comment: That's great example, but `but it's not working` - how are you checking it's "not working"? And what do you want to `memcpy`? `5` characters? or `5` pointers? What should `memcpy(a + 5, b, 5);` do and what should the result be?

Comment: I want to copy 5 pointers, I check immediately the value of a after I pass the memcpy, it seems to be working if I put sizeof(B) and sizeof(A) instead of 5 in the memcpy.

Comment: "it's not working" is not a problem description. At best, it's a complaint :-) but it conveys no useful information, and without useful information in the question, you can't get useful responses. Please try to describe in concrete terms what you expect your code to do, what you observe that it does (and how you observe that) and why what it does does not match your expectations.

Comment: You should *always* write allocation (in C) according to the following model: `char ** b = malloc(10 * sizeof(*b));`. Note that the type of the pointer being allocated is only written once, so there is no chance of bugs from a incorrectly written type. (Unfortunately you have to write the name of the variable twice. But that's less likely to create an unnoticed error.)

Comment: Also, please recall that in C *allocated objects don't know their size*. `sizeof` is computed at compile-time, and is the size of its argument, *not* whatever its argument might be pointing to if its argument happens to be a pointer. If you need to know the number of elements in an array (or the number of characters in a string), you need to remember that from when you created the array. (For a string, you could get the standard library to count the characters with `strlen`, but that's pretty inefficient compared with knowing (remembering) the count.)

Comment: @rici Thanks for your replies, so if I wanted to copy all the arrays in b I need to calculate first theirs length (in my example it will be 5*strlen("tes")), right ?

Comment: You can't copy 5 arrays with a single memcpy. You need to copy each array separately. And you need somewhere to copy them to. Allocating space to store a pointer does not initialise the pointer to anything; it just gives you somewhere to put a pointer. Pointers are real things. You have to treat them as such.

Comment: for what I wanted to do, is not to duplicate the arrays, but just copy their pointers and put them in a array of pointers.

Comment: @kml2019: if you don't want to copy the strings, why would `strlen("tes")` be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy five elements from the array b to the five positions starting at index 5 in array a, you don't want:

> `memcpy(&a + 5, &b, 5);`

It should be

```
memcpy(a + 5, b, 5 * sizeof(*b)); // See Note below
```

That's independent of the type of what `a` and `b` point to.

But note that if `a` and `b` point to pointers, then only the pointers are being copied. So if `a` and `b` are arrays of character strings -- `char**` -- then you'll end up with `a[5]` being the same pointer as `b[0]`. That might be fine, but it could also be a problem. For example, if you modify some character in `b[0]`, the string pointed to be `a[5]` (which is the same string) will also be changed. And, critically, if you `free(b[0])`, then `a[5]` is no longer a valid pointer, so you cannot refer to it or `free` it.

Not copying the character strings can save you a lot of memory, but the memory sharing comes at a huge price in bookkeeping. It's often simpler to make new strings, which means that you need to use something like `strdup` (or you could write out the `malloc` and the `strcpy`, but `strdup` is less bug-prone).

---

#### Note

`a` and `b` are variables with addresses. `&a` and `&b` are the addresses of the variables. Since `a` is a scalar variable, `&a + 5` is undefined behaviour. It points at somewhere else in your function's local stack frame (if the stack frame is big enough), which means to some other local variable. But you don't know which variable, and you don't have any right to describe it that way, even if you knew which one it was.

What you're interested in is the address of the sixth slot in the array `a` points at, which is `a + 5` (thanks to C pointer arithmetic) or `&a[5]`, which many people would say is clearer.

Also, like `malloc`, `memcpy` counts in bytes, not elements (since it doesn't know the element size). So a count of 5 means "5 bytes", which you'll find is a lot less than five pointers. (Indeed, it's probably less than one pointer.)